# Will this SQLite based Python code be compatible with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, python-3.x, pymysql

I have a Python 3 application that uses SQLite directly, by executing SQL code strings (i.e., without using a ORM like SQLalchemy). The database is being initialized like this:

```
def db_inicialize():
    global DB_PATH
    print(" - Opening database...\n", DB_PATH)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
    c = conn.cursor()
    print(" - Locating or creating database...")
    try:
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dados (
                id                INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                destin            TEXT NOT NULL,
                estado            TEXT,
                obj_num           TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                data_exp          DATETIME,
                valor_cobr        TEXT,
                chq_recebido      TEXT,
                data_depositar    TEXT,
                vols              INTEGER,
                rma               TEXT,
                expedidor         TEXT NOT NULL,
                obs               TEXT,
                arquivado         BOOLEAN,
                data_depositado   DATETIME,
                data_ult_verif    DATETIME,
                data_ult_alt      DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                estado_detalhado  TEXT
                )""")
    except:
        print(" - It was not possible to create the main table in database.")
        return False
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
```

Then I am running code like this to change things in the database:

```
def db_update_estado(info):
    global DB_PATH
    estado = verificar_estado(info)
    if estado != "- N/A -":
        estado_detalhado = obter_estado_detalhado(info)
        agora = datetime.now()
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute("""UPDATE dados SET estado = ?, estado_detalhado = ?, data_ult_verif = ? WHERE obj_num = ?;""", (estado, estado_detalhado, agora, remessa))
            conn.commit()
            c.close()
        except:
            print(" - It was not possible to update this register in the database!")
```

Is it safe to use, for instance `import pymysql`, adjust the database connection statements and keep all the SQL related code? Or will I need to revise all the SQL code, change data types in the table initialization...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

MySQL and SQLite are different databases.  They do have a lot of similarities, so if you are careful, you may be able to get code that would work in both.  But I wouldn't plan on it.

For instance, your `create table` statement as `text unique`.  This is not supported in MySQL.  You would need to use `varchar(xxx)` where xxx is less than some value (I would use a practical maximum of 255).

There are numerous differences in the handling of date/time values.  For instance, `curdate()` versus `date('now')`, and lots of differences in other functions as well.  SQLite supports CTEs; MySQL does not.

I would recommend that you build the data-base specific functionality in its own modules.  Or, use a common interface such as pandas.

Comment: I will explore it a little further before I start actually porting the code into MySQL.